# Issue with set span applying bold

Tags: android, text, fonts

I am trying to set a string to have alternating bolding and not bolding for a FAQ section and I am seeing something strange. Only one set of questions and answers receives the correct span. When debugging I see there is only two spans set on the string builder. Shouldn't it append a new span for each set span call ?

```
  (activity as MainActivity).settingsPresenter.getFaq(
                    { success, message,value ->
                        if(success) {
                            var sb : SpannableStringBuilder = SpannableStringBuilder("")
                            var fcs : ForegroundColorSpan =  ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255))
                            var styleBold : StyleSpan = StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD)
                            var styleNotBold : StyleSpan = StyleSpan(Typeface.NORMAL)

                            for (i in 0..value?.size!! - 1){
                                sb.append(value?.get(i)?.Question + "\n\n")
                                sb.setSpan(styleBold, startLocation, startLocation + value?.get(i)?.Question?.length!!, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
                                startLocation += value?.get(i)?.Question?.length!! + 2//update the start location pointer to color the next section of text

                                sb.append(value?.get(i)?.Answer + "\n\n")
                                sb.setSpan(styleNotBold, startLocation, startLocation + value?.get(i)?.Answer?.length!!, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
                                startLocation += value?.get(i)?.Answer?.length!! + 2
                            }

                            faq_content.append(sb)

                        }
                    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this with this solution:

```
 for (i in 0..value?.size!! - 1) {
                            var sb : SpannableStringBuilder = SpannableStringBuilder()
                            sb.append(value?.get(i)?.Question)
                            sb.append("\n\n")
                            sb.setSpan(StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), 0, sb.length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
                            sb.append(value?.get(i)?.Answer)
                            sb.append("\n\n")
                            faq_content.append(sb)
                        }
```

Cheers !